# Timeouts in Winsock programming

Tags: c, windows, winsock

I'm working on a basic UDP socket file transfer server/client setup, using go-back-n windowing, and unfortunately am stuck doing it using Winsock due to assignment constraints.

Normally in order to manage timeouts on outstanding packets I would just use signal() but am unsure as to how/if this actually really works on Windows, and if this is actually the best solution. Is there some best way to handle these sorts of socket timeouts? Or am I best just managing timeouts with select()?

Answer (score 0):

If your application has a "main()" function then using select() to manage timeouts is the most convenient as it has the advantage that it uses only socket api calls, so the code should work on any platform supporting a bsd style socket api and doesn't require a windows message loop.

If you are writing a window GUI style application - usually with a `WinMain()` entry point and a message loop, then `WSAAsyncSelect`() on a socket handle will get read (and write) ready notification messages posted to a HWND - `SetTimer` likewise posts periodic `WM_TIMER` notifications, and `GetTickCount` can be used to detect which socket has been idle too long.